# jQuery find closest hidden input where name attribute contains ID

Tags: jquery

I have a list of checkboxes. Each one has associated data inserted in hidden inputs. When a checkbox is `checked` I want to find the closest hidden input where the name contains the string "ID". I get a "undefined" error when I `alert(obj.val());`. The ID within the name is dynamic so I cannot use the exact name.

```js
$('.cb-org').change(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    var obj = $(this).closest('input:hidden[name*="ID"]');
    alert(obj.val());
  }
});
```

```css
li{
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
  <input type="hidden" name="OrganisationEntities[0].Name" value="My Org 2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="OrganisationEntities[0].ID" value="1" />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb-org" />
    My Org
  </label>
</li>
<li>
  <input type="hidden" name="OrganisationEntities[1].Name" value="My Org" />
  <input type="hidden" name="OrganisationEntities[1].ID" value="2" />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb-org" />
    My Org 2
  </label>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All we need to do is move up from the checkbox to the containing `li` element, then find the hidden input that contains "ID" in the name attribute.

```js
$('.cb-org').change(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    var obj = $(this).closest('li').find('input:hidden[name*="ID"]');
    alert(obj.val());
  }
});
```

```css
li{
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
  <input type="hidden" name="OrganisationEntities[0].Name" value="My Org 2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="OrganisationEntities[0].ID" value="1" />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb-org" />
    My Org
  </label>
</li>
<li>
  <input type="hidden" name="OrganisationEntities[1].Name" value="My Org" />
  <input type="hidden" name="OrganisationEntities[1].ID" value="2" />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb-org" />
    My Org 2
  </label>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @mr.coffee you might want to change `name*="ID"` to `name$="ID"`. This will only check for names ending in `ID` while the previous way will match if `ID` appears *anywhere* in the name.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify your query considerably if you moved your hidden inputs inside the label

```
<label >
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb-org" />
  My Org
  <input type="hidden" name="OrganisationEntities[0].Name" value="My Org 2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="OrganisationEntities[0].ID" value="1" />
</label>
```

Or if you moved your checkbox outside the label and used a `for` attribute to link it to the label

```
<input id="my-checkbox-id" type="checkbox" class="cb-org" />
<label for="my-checkbox-id">
  My Org
</label>
<input type="hidden" name="OrganisationEntities[0].Name" value="My Org 2" />
<input type="hidden" name="OrganisationEntities[0].ID" value="1" />
```

In both cases, the checkbox and the hidden inputs would be siblings, allowing for simpler queries, such as

```
$('.cb-org').on('change', function() {
  $checkbox = $(this) // cache "this" so we don't have to re-select it

  if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
    var $hidden = $checkbox.siblings('input:hidden[name$="ID"]').first()
    alert($hidden.val())
  }
});
```

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar Don't worry, I didn't down vote you. The only difference is I suggested altering the HTML to make the Javascript easier to write.

Answer (score -1):

I assume your **OrganisationEntities[1].ID** get some **ID** contains **ID** so try this

```js
$('.cb-org').change(function(){
 if ($(this).is(':checked')){
   var obj = $(this).closest('li').find('input:hidden[name*="ID"]');
    if(obj.length < 1){
      obj = $(this).closest('ul').find('input:hidden[name*="ID"]');
      if(obj.length < 1){
        alert('ID NOT EXIST');
        return false;
      }
    }
    alert(obj.val())
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
  <input type="hidden" name="NAMEICONTAINID" value="idiotValueName1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="" value="idiotValueID" />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb-org" />
    1
  </label>
  </li>
<li>
  <input type="hidden" name="NAMEICONTAIN" value="idiotValueName2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="" value="idiotValueID2" />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cb-org" />
    2
  </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Try this if you don't understand hope someone does

First i search on current closest parent if it exist alert it,
Second i search on outer Parent of current parent if it exist same does alert it.

As you can see if name contains ID it selecting that input if you want to try change id to something else but ID to check it

Comment: Thank you but this won't work because the ID `[1]` is dynamic.

Comment: You dont get it do you. Change it with your ID check again i have to do it again for your desire

Comment: The whole point is to get the ID from the hidden input. If I already knew the ID then none of this would be necessary.

Comment: Your question was to get value from closest hidden input with name contains id is that correct?

Comment: Yes. I need to get the hidden input where the name field contains the string "ID". Not the actual ID because I don't know it.

Comment: Do you get it @mr.coffee